# javascript / ajax runs on localhost - not on heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I use javascript to update a partial on my website.

I am telling the controller to respond to js format:

```
  def statistic
    @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
    @tickers = @game.tickers

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @game }
    end
  end
```

and I have a statistic.js.erb file in my view folder like this:

```
$("#main").html("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'home/statistic.html.erb', :handlers => [:erb]) %>");
```

It works on my localhost. That means the statistic page opens in the main-frame. But when I deploy on heroku it opens a new page.

Here is the log of my localhost:

> ... Processing by HomeController#statistic as JS ...

This ist the heroku log:

> ... Processing by HomeController#statistic as HTML ...

I guess the problem is that javascript isn't installed or implemented on my heroku account? This is my gemfile. Perhaps that helps:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
gem 'simple_form'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Do you know what to do? Thanks for help.

Comment: Does nobody have an idea how to solve my problem? I read several topics where javascript works on localhost but not on heroku. But no answer helped me with my problem. I guess it should have something to do with the gemfile. Help is still appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

before pushing to heroku helped me

Comment: Yeah, normally Heroku does that automatically but if for some reason it didn't that might solve your problem.